# How to design a state flow for a react/redux flashcard game?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my first redux project. I'm trying to make a flashcard game that teaches you hiragana/katakana. I'm getting stuck on some of the state flow...

**Game state visualization**

```js
{
  // the current displayed card
  currentCard: null | {q: 'き', a: 'ki'},

  // time the game was started
  timestamp: millisecondTimestamp,

  // submitted answers
  answers: [
    {
      card: {q: 'か', a: 'ka'},
      answer: 'ka'
    },
    {
      card: {q: 'な', a: 'na'},
      answer: 'na'
    },
    ...
  ],

  // remaining cards in the deck
  deck: [
    {q: 'く', a: 'ku'},
    {q: 'け', a: 'ke'},
    {q: 'こ', a: 'ko'}
    ...
  ]
}
```

**stores/game.js**

```js
import {BEGIN_GAME, NEXT_CARD, SUBMIT_ANSWER} from '../actions/';
import {isEmpty, first, rest} from '../utilities/';

const gameReducer = (state=null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case BEGIN_GAME:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {deck: action.deck});

    case NEXT_CARD:
      return isEmpty(state.deck)
        ? Object.assign({}, state, {
          currentCard: null
        })
        : Object.assign({}, state, {
          currentCard: first(state.deck),
          deck: rest(state.deck)
        })
      ;

    case SUBMIT_ANSWER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        currentCard: null,
        answers: state.answers.concat({
          card: state.currentCard,
          answer: action.answer
        })
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default gameReducer;
```

**actions/index.js**

```js
import {shuffle} from '../utilities/';

export const BEGIN_GAME = 'BEGIN_GAME';
export const NEXT_CARD = 'NEXT_CARD';
export const SUBMIT_ANSWER = 'SUBMIT_ANSWER';

export const beginGame = deck => ({
  type: BEGIN_GAME,
  deck: shuffle(deck)
});

export const nextCard = () => ({
  type: NEXT_CARD
});

export const submitAnswer = answer => ({
  type: SUBMIT_ANSWER,
  answer
});
```

I'm thinking the game loop will work something like this:

- when `state` is `null`, wait for user to press <kbd>Begin game</kbd> button which dispatches `BEGIN_GAME` action
- At this point, begin the main game loop
- Dispatch `CHECK_END_GAME` to determine if any cards remain in the deck
- Dispatch `NEXT_CARD` to display the next card on the deck
- Wait for an answer to be clicked, then dispatch a `SUBMIT_ANSWER` action
- After the answer is recorded, repeat the loop, starting with `CHECK_END_GAME`, followed by `NEXT_CARD`, followed by waiting for `SUBMIT_ANSWER`, etc
- At some point `CHECK_END_GAME` should trigger a `DISPLAY_RESULTS` action... ??

See, I'm getting a little lost here... With redux, I don't think I can (or should) dispatch another action from *within* a store. But then how do I decompose these actions or state checks ?

My brain is currently thinking with a model like this:

```
BEGIN_GAME(deck)

LOOP(
  CHECK_END_GAME()->NEXT_CARD()->SUBMIT_ANSWER(answer)->
)

DISPLAY_RESULTS()
```

The problem is, I don't know how to chain actions like this, or if it's even advised. I'm open to designing the actions/store in a completely different way. I'm a noob here, so just tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Any nudge in the proper direction will be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: I would suggest you to describe the control flow with [Redux Saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga), and use Redux primarily for updating the state rather than for the control flow logic. Redux Saga lets you write a game loop with ES6 generators that `take` and `put` Redux actions.

Comment: @DanAbramov I'm so excited to have gotten a reply from you ! I will certainly check it out **^__^**

Comment: @DanAbramov So I've done some reading on the Saga Pattern, watched the [Applying Saga Pattern video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDuwrtwYHu8) from the Redux Saga docs, and played around with some of the Redux Saga examples. Before I move forward with attempting to use this, I just want to be clear that my game is a purely local/synchronous game with the possible exception of loading the full deck asynchronously once before the first game, and asynchronously submitting stats after the game ends.

Comment: @DanAbramov it seems like the Saga Pattern is maybe more geared toward apps with a high degree of asynchronous behaviour. If you still think it's applicable, do you think you could provide a starting point for me to work off of? I would be immensely grateful.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I haven’t read deeply into what your app does which is why I left a comment rather than an answer. Sagas are asynchronous in the sense that user inputs are asynchronous. Not sure whether this is helpful to you. I think the biggest problem with your question is I don’t understand if the code you posted works, or if you have problems with it. It is a little unclear. Have you got it working?

Comment: @DanAbramov OK so I've been hard-at-work understanding redux-saga. I have to say, if I'm understanding it correctly, it's quite an amazing bit of kit, even if much of your app is synchronous. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/naomik/00f10e5bbbd15951c736) of some of the code I was able to put together. I'm a total rookie in almost all things React (and new to Redux as of February), so I'd appreciate any feedback. If I'm doing dumb stuff, I would rather know. Otherwise, if this code is acceptable, I will do a write up and post another answer to this question.

Comment: @DanAbramov ps thank you (et al) so much for Redux. I'm really enjoying working with it.

Comment: What you wrote looks sensible. I would try to avoid local state in sagas and use `put()` and `select()` more but there is no single way to do things.

Answer (score 4):

One way to code the application is to model (or to organize) the game logic in terms of Petri Net Elements and based on this organization write the code (Chionglo, 2014). The following is an example of a game logic (based on a Flashcard game) organized in terms of Petri Nets (“How to Design”, 2016). In this game there are nine cards. One card is shown at a time then the player guesses the card.  The number of correct guesses and the number of incorrect guesses are recorded and play continues until there are no more cards to display.

Figure 1 ([for the PDF version of this reply](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/oejOw1455338124.pdf)) is an interactive, dynamic diagram of the game logic; it includes “graphic notations” of cards with standard Petri Net notations and some high-level notations of Petri Net elements. The demonstration mode of the game logic randomly selects a card from the deck then randomly guesses the card.

[image: Labels and Descriptions of Petri Net Elements]

[image: Petri Net Model of the Game]

### References

Chionglo, J. F. (2016). A Reply to "How to design a state flow for a react/redux flashcard game?" at Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow. https://www.academia.edu/34059934/A_Reply_to_How_to_design_a_state_flow_for_a_react_redux_flashcard_game_at_Stack_Overflow.

Chionglo, J. F. (2014). Net Elements and Annotations for Computer Programming: Computations and Interactions in PDF. https://www.academia.edu/26906314/Net_Elements_and_Annotations_for_Computer_Programming_Computations_and_Interactions_in_PDF.

“How to design a state flow for a react/redux flashcard game?” (2016). Stack Exchange. Retrieved on Feb. 7, 2016 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220169/how-to-design-a-state-flow-for-a-react-redux-flashcard-game.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very academic reply. I can't say I've ever gotten such a detailed response to one of my questions before. I've never heard of Petri Net Elements before so it's going to be a bit of a learning curve for me, but it all looks quite interesting. I'll be sure to follow up with whatever solution ends up working for me.

Comment: You are so very welcome. I hope you find the information helpful and practical. Good luck on your project and keep us posted.

Comment: Some of the references in this reply are incorrect due to changes in file locations. Instead of editing this reply I created a new version of this reply and it is available at https://www.academia.edu/34115722/A_Reply_to_How_to_design_a_flashcard_game_Movement_to_a_New_Web_Site_and_Its_Recreation_in_this_Version.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: this answer will be a little rushed, I have a train to catch*

Currently, I only "chain" async actions but I guess the same principle could apply.

I don't really understand this game :P, But suspect you should be thinking about it a little more like this:

```
BEGIN_GAME(deck)

DISPLAY_STATE
    {if END_GAME()}
        Its over!
    {else}
        <button onclick=dispatch( drawCardAndModifyStateAction )/>
```

In your parent reducer you might *compose* (as opposed to chain) your reducers:

```
const gameReducer = (state=null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    NEXT_CARD: state.nextCard = nextCard(state);
  }
  state.checkEndGame = checkEndGame(state);
  return state;
}
```

Your `nextCard` "sub" reducer does some stuff...

```
const nextCard = (state=null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEXT_CARD:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          currentCard: first(state.deck),
          isEmpty: isEmpty(state.deck),
          deck: rest(state.deck)
        })
    }
  return state;
}
```

Followed by `checkEndGame`

```
const checkEndGame = (state=null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          message: ...,
          winner: ...,
        })
    }
}
```

You might also look into middleware like [redux saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga), [redux thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk).